# Can we used Maven as build tool for protractor

Tags: maven, protractor, cucumber

So i am trying to create a protractor test with cucumber and use Maven as build tool and project management tool .Is it a feasible combination using Maven with cucumber and protractor. If yes ,please advice how.

Comment: Isn't protractor an Angular tool? It seems more logical to me to use a javascript build tool

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use maven as a build tool for cucumber project, here is the link i am providing which is the best official link of cucumber in which they have mentioned every thing in a clean way.
https://docs.cucumber.io/guides/10-minute-tutorial/
you can refer this link it will clear all your confusion and you'll have clear vision of  using maven in your project.